# Impossible to delete files from USB stick

Tags: usb

After running this command:

```
sudo cp MyFile.iso /dev/sdb && sync
```

it's now impossible to delete files from the USB stick. 
I get the following message:

```
Error removing file: File system in read only mode
```

The USB stick seems properly mounted/umounted by the system and I can see the files on the stick.
However

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

gives a weird result as there is no number after the USB device (ie: sdb) whereas the stick is mounted:

```
Disk /dev/sdb : 15 GiB, 16039018496 octets, 31326208 sectors Unités :
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What does the `mount` command tell you? In particular, look for `ro` in the output for this device. Also, you used `dd`, not `cp` to burn the ISO to the USB drive, right? Otherwise, I think you just overwrote your device file; do `ls -l /dev/sdb` to see if it's still a character/block device or just a regular file.

Comment: `sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/username/`     

`mount: /dev/sdb is write-protected, mounting read-only`

Comment: You do realize the ISO filesystem is readonly, right? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26237/iso-file-readonly

Comment: Yes. But now how can I remove that ISO filesystem from the USB key ?

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Use something like 'mke2fs' to create a new filesystem, or you can even use `dd` to copy a bunch of nulls to /dev/sdb. I'm surprised your `cp` command worked, btw.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you show me an example with mke2fs and dd as I'm not familiar with these commands ?

Comment: Try googling or using `man`. If that still doesn't work, we can take this to chat. Make sure you have nothing valuable on the USB stick since both commands will "destroy" any stored data.

Comment: `sudo mkfs.vfat -n 'Ubuntu' -I /dev/sdb`  command has deleted the files but it's still in readonly mode as I cannot copy any file in it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the cloned system inherits the iso9660 file system, which is read-only by design. After you have finished using the USB drive as an Ubuntu boot drive, you can

- restore the USB drive to a standard storage device. **`mkusb`** can create an MSDOS partition table with a FAT32 partition automatically and you select it from the main menu in mkusb version 12 (mkusb-dus).

  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

  If you run standard Ubuntu, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
  ```

  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe
- use some other partitioning tool if you want to create something more advanced (than a standard storage device). **`gparted`** is a good tool with an intuitive graphical user interface.